# Compiled modified cleos

Tags: development

I've made some changes to the `main.cpp` file in the folder `/programs/cleos/`. How can i compile only this file? I've tried with `g++ main.cpp` but i have to link all the include directories using `-I` and it's a quite tedious task. There is a faster way to do that, for instance to include all the directories at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened an issue on github and a developer answered me with this:

> Just run make or `make -j8` in your build directory. CMake generates Makefiles which do dependency checking. If you have modified only `programs/cleos/main.cpp`, only `cleos` will be rebuilt.
>
> A slightly safer way of accomplishing the same thing which will also detect some changes to the build environment is `cmake --build . --target all`. Append `-- -j8` if you wish to run a parallel build.